# Utilizar etiqueta CSS dentro de código PHP de WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy intentando mostrar/ocultar dos líneas de texto en función de si una categoría de `WooCommerce` está vacía o tiene algún producto. Esas líneas están insertadas en bloques de texto mediante `Elementor` y a cada una le he asignado un `#ID` de `CSS`, para poder controlarlo.

Ahora, en un plugin de funciones personalizadas que tengo, quiero añadir una función para que controle que frase ocultar mediante una regla de `css` del tipo: `display:none;`. El código que tengo ahora es:

```php
function show_outlet_msg($content){
    $term = get_term( 40, 'product_cat' );
    $total_products=$term->count;
    if ($total_products>0){
        //Hay productos 
    } else {
        //No hay productos
    }
}

add_filter('astra_entry_content_before','show_outlet_msg');
```

Ahora me gustaría aplicar que si hay productos en Outlet, se oculte el texto de que no hay:

```css
#txt_outlet_zero{
display: none;
}
```

Y en el caso de que no haya productos, ocultar el que dice que si:

```css
#txt_outlet_head{
display: none;
}
```

¿Como puedo aplicar estas reglas `CSS` desde el código `php`?

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar a hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    function show_outlet_msg($content){
    $term = get_term( 40, 'product_cat' );
    $total_products=$term->count;
    if ($total_products>0){
        //Hay productos 
        echo '<span class="txt_outlet_zero">' . $term . '</span>';
    } else {
        //No hay productos
        echo '<span class="txt_outlet_head">' . $term . '</span>';
    }
    }
    add_filter('astra_entry_content_before','show_outlet_msg');
```